# importing issue with mysql version to another

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, database-administration

I have got an issue with mysql import, I have taken a backup of the mysql version 5.1.32 with the help of command `mysqldump -u root -p --routines oneclicksite > oneclick.sql` and importing it with the command `mysql -u username -p mycon < oneclicksite.sql`  in to mysql 5.1.73 in to my ubuntu 10.04 system. After importing I have checked all the tables and procedures,some of tables not created and all procedures not imported. When i try import in 5.5 version of the mysql, it was imported correctly, now my question is  What are the options I have to import the database correctly in 5.1.73 ? I have tried to degrade the version to 5.1.32 i have faced so many issues, can any one help me?

Comment: Could You please show, how You're exporting/importing those tables? My guts are telling, that You're forgetting the `--routines` while exporting or/and importing flag.

Comment: mysqldump -u root -p --routines oneclicksite > oneclick.sql

Comment: mysql -u username -p mycon < oneclicksite.sql

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information.

Comment: Have you tried using the Workbench migration wizard?  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-migration-database-mysql.html